Are server actions called in the client component bundled and sent to the client?
I am developing an application using Next.js v14 with the app router.
I am creating functions for data retrieval, etc., using server actions. Initially, I understood that importing functions defined with server actions into a client component would cause the code to be bundled and leaked to the client side. Therefore, I believed that 'server-only' existed to prevent this.
However, upon checking in the browser, I could not find the parts corresponding to the server action contents. If the code does not leak, it means that I can call server action functions in the client component without any concerns. Is my understanding correct? I am getting confused because different articles state different things.
// app/actions/post.ts
"use server";
// import "server-only";

export async function getPosts() {
  // test
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}


// app/page.tsx
"use client";
import { getPosts } from "@/app/actions/post";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function page() {
  async function fetchPosts() {
    const post = await getPosts();
    console.log(post);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>post</h3>
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchPosts} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



Initially, I understood that importing functions defined with server
actions into a client component would cause the code to be bundled and
leaked to the client side. Therefore, I believed that 'server-only'
existed to prevent this.

No, Server Components and Server Actions don't cause any code leak. They run on the server and only the calculated response is sent to client. For Server Components, server responds to the client with chunks of data that contains React Server Component Payload (RSC Payload) and then these chunks are rendered on the client. You can see how rendering of Server Components work on this documentation page section of Next.js. Additionally, server-only allows you to restrict access or import of a module flagged with use-server. When you import use-server to a module flagged with use-server it can not be imported from a client component and this goes the same for client-only package. Description of server-only package's package.json file:

This is a marker package to indicate that a module can only be used in Server Components.


However, upon checking in the browser, I could not find the parts
corresponding to the server action contents. If the code does not
leak, it means that I can call server action functions in the client
component without any concerns. Is my understanding correct? I am
getting confused because different articles state different things.

Yes, your understanding is right. I would recommend you to read documentation sections Data Fetching and Rendering. These documentation pages explain what's going on behind the scenes pretty well.

Thank you for your response.
The Next.js documentation includes the following content:

「"use client" is used to declare a boundary between a Server and Client Component modules. This means that by defining a "use client" in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle.
」

I thought that the actions functions imported from here would also be included in the bundle, but that is not the case.

Yes, that's not the case. But again, Next.js uses a tree system to determine components. When you import a Server Component or Server Action into your client module, that code doesn't become a Client Component and expose all it's content or sensitive data like API keys, connection strings etc. In this case, imported Server Component or Server Action is still a server-side code which is inside server boundary whereas the Client Component is inside client boundary.

At the bottom of the same documentation page you've shared: "Sometimes, after you've declared the "use client" boundary, you may want to go back to the server environment. For example, you may want to reduce the client bundle size, fetch data on the server, or use an API that is only available on the server.
You can keep code on the server even though it's theoretically nested inside Client Components by interleaving Client and Server Components and Server Actions. See the Composition Patterns page for more information."

What you are doing is interleaving Client and Server Components. The server action is imported into client component but it's still inside the Server Boundary.

I see.
I will read the documentation carefully once again.
Thank you.
